# Javascript variables inside if else statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, scope, global-variables

I have a custom volume bar and mute button in my music player. Muting is very simple, but I want to return the previous volume when the button is clicked for the second time.

**Example:** Let's say the current volume is at `50%`. Clicking the mute button will change it to `0`. Clicking it again should get it back to `50%`.

This is how I tried it:

```
var music = document.getElementById('music');
var volumehead = document.getElementById('volume-head');
var volumebar = document.getElementById('volume-bar');
var mute = document.getElementById('mute');

mute.addEventListener("click", muteSound);

function muteSound(){
    if(mute.classList.contains('not-muted')){
        // Save current values before changing them
        var lastHead = volumehead.style.marginLeft;
        var lastVolume = music.volume;

        // Change classname for appearance and next click
        mute.className = "muted";

        // Change values to 0
        volumehead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        music.volume = 0;
    } else {
        // Change classname for appearance and next click
        mute.className = "not-muted";

        // Use saved values
        volumehead.style.marginLeft = lastHead;
        music.volume = lastVolume;
    }
}
```

The 2 `variables` that hold the position of the handler and the volume are given a value within the `if-statement`, meaning they don't have one in the `else-statement`.

Declaring them outside of the statements means that the values will be "overwritten" by `0`.

Is there a way to save the values and use them for the next click on the button?

---

**Edit (solution):**
The values that the `if-statement` assigned to the `variables`, could only be used by the `else-statement` if the `variables` were declared *outside* of the `function`.

Comment: *The 2 variables that hold the position of the handler and the volume are declared within the if-statement, meaning they're not accessible in the else-statement* - This is not true when using `var`, they're hoisted to the top of the function. A variable is only scoped to a statement block when using `let` or `const`. Anyway, the solution to your issue is to declare the variables outside of the function

Comment: You need to save the volume in a variable outside the function `muteSound`, i.e. together where all your other `volumebar` variables etc. are. Conceptually: you should attach an event handler to the volumebar which updates that `volume` variable every time it's moved; so `volume` always contains the currently chosen volume. When `mute` is clicked you mute the volume and render your UI to indicate a muted volume; **you do not change the value of `volume`.** When unmuting you restore the volume and update the UI again.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm When I console.log the variables both in the if- and else-statements, the ones in the else-statement return `undefined`.

Comment: @PeterPrakker Yes, they are never assigned a value, that happens in the if-block. But they ARE declared, thanks to hoisting, otherwise it wouldn't log `undefined`, it would throw a `ReferenceError` saying `lastHead is not defined`. You can see the difference for yourself by changing `var` to `let`.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Ah, you're right. I edited my statement in the question. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var music = document.getElementById('music');
var volumehead = document.getElementById('volume-head');
var volumebar = document.getElementById('volume-bar');
var mute = document.getElementById('mute');

var lastHead, lastVolume;

mute.addEventListener("click", muteSound);

function muteSound() {
    if (mute.classList.contains('not-muted')) {
        // Save current values before changing them
        lastHead = volumehead.style.marginLeft;
        lastVolume = music.volume;

        // Change classname for appearance and next click
        mute.className = "muted";

        // Change values to 0
        volumehead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        music.volume = 0;
    } else {
        // Change classname for appearance and next click
        mute.className = "not-muted";

        // Use saved values
        volumehead.style.marginLeft = lastHead;
        music.volume = lastVolume;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IIFE ([immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) with a closure over `lastHead` and `lastVolume`;

```
var muteSound = function () {
    var lastHead, lastVolume;

    return function () {
        if (mute.classList.contains('not-muted')) {
            // Save current values before changing them
            lastHead = volumehead.style.marginLeft;
            lastVolume = music.volume;

            // Change classname for appearance and next click
            mute.className = "muted";

            // Change values to 0
            volumehead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
            music.volume = 0;
        } else {
            // Change classname for appearance and next click
            mute.className = "not-muted";

            // Use saved values
            volumehead.style.marginLeft = lastHead;
            music.volume = lastVolume;
        }
    };
}();

mute.addEventListener("click", muteSound);
```

Comment: @deceze will making the function 'static' solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
mute.addEventListener("click", muteSound);
var lastHead = "10px";
var lastVolume = 10;

function muteSound(){
if(mute.classList.contains('not-muted')){
    // Save current values before changing them
    lastHead = volumehead.style.marginLeft;
    lastVolume = music.volume;

    // Change classname for appearance and next click
    mute.className = "muted";

    // Change values to 0
    volumehead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    music.volume = 0;
} else {
    // Change classname for appearance and next click
    mute.className = "not-muted";

    // Use saved values
    volumehead.style.marginLeft = lastHead;
    music.volume = lastVolume;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable outside of your loop and assign it to the volume before it gets set to 0. Then reference that variable in your else statement!